# Assigning color for grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Was just wondering why the color of the dots weren't changed albeit I was using the `scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired")` command to manually assign the colors. Thanks

My image

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkMPS.png)

My script

```
psbsrd <- read_csv("psbs rd.csv")

psbsrd$gen=factor(psbsrd$gen,levels=c("WT","PsbS","T259A","T259D","T259E","T259S","S265-","T79A/S104A/T259A","T79D/S104E/T259D"))

ggplot(psbsrd, aes(x=gen, y=rd,color=gen)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
   geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center',
               stackratio=1, dotsize=0.7)+theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))+
  labs(x= "",  y="PsbS relative density")
```

My data frame

```
data.frame(psbsrd)
   id              gen        rd
1   1               WT 1.0000000
2   2             PsbS 1.2211420
3   3             PsbS 1.5918041
4   4             PsbS 2.1668718
5   5             PsbS 2.6198157
6   6             PsbS 1.5571007
7   7             PsbS 1.0520551
8   8             PsbS 0.4648043
9   9             PsbS 1.9454836
10 10            S265- 1.5497361
11 11            S265- 3.2732440
12 12            S265- 4.3479497
13 13            S265- 4.8951613
14 14            S265- 6.2919204
15 15            S265- 7.7251320
16 16 T79A/S104A/T259A 0.1784396
17 17 T79A/S104A/T259A 0.5977111
18 18 T79A/S104A/T259A 0.5307654
19 19 T79A/S104A/T259A 3.0679723
20 20 T79D/S104E/T259D 1.2229263
21 21            T259A 0.9812587
22 22            T259A 0.9647552
23 23            T259A 0.9001399
24 24            T259A 1.6814516
25 25            T259A 2.3471329
26 26            T259A 2.6215385
27 27            T259D 2.9000576
28 28            T259D 2.8604196
29 29            T259D 3.3292308
30 30            T259D 3.3822005
31 31            T259D 2.9608392
32 32            T259D 2.6813986
33 33            T259D 2.6746853
34 34            T259D 1.6584615
35 35            T259D 2.9927273
36 36            T259E 1.4003248
37 37            T259E 1.6272838
38 38            T259E 1.8465286
39 39            T259E 3.5475230
40 40            T259E 2.2281770
41 41            T259E 2.1733658
42 42            T259S 4.4847350
43 43            T259S 4.9366626
44 44            T259S 2.2005684
```

Comment: try with `aes(... , fill = gen)` and `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")`

Comment: @wychin Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should add in `ggplot` function, what variable you want the filling to be applied to, e.g. `gen`, in the following example

Then you can use `scale_fill_brewer` to fill the dots instead of coloring the frame of the latest.

```
### Import library
library(ggplot2)

### Data simulation
psbsrd <- data.frame(id=1:44,
                    rd=rnorm(44, 2, 0.5), 
                    gen=rep(c("WT","PsbS","T259A","T259D","T259E","T259S","S265-","T79A/S104A/T259A","T79D/S104E/T259D"), each=5)[-1])
psbsrd$gen <- factor(psbsrd$gen, levels=c("WT","PsbS","T259A","T259D","T259E","T259S","S265-","T79A/S104A/T259A","T79D/S104E/T259D"))

### Plot with scale_fill_brewer
ggplot(psbsrd, aes(x=gen, y=rd, fill=gen)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', stackratio=1, dotsize=0.7) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) + 
  labs(x= "",  y="PsbS relative density")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `fill` instead of `color` in `aes`

```r
library(ggplot2)

data$gen=factor(data$gen,levels=c("WT","PsbS","T259A","T259D","T259E","T259S","S265-","T79A/S104A/T259A","T79D/S104E/T259D"))

ggplot(data, aes(x=gen, y=rd,fill=gen)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center',
               stackratio=1, dotsize=0.7)+theme(text = element_text(size = 20))+theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))+
  labs(x= "",  y="PsbS relative density")
#> Bin width defaults to 1/30 of the range of the data. Pick better value with
#> `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both work wells! Hence it depends if you'd prefer to modify the filling or frame of the dots via "fill" or "color" command, respectively.